# How to efficiently update app widget

Tags: java, android, android-widget, widget, android-appwidget

I'm developing a music player .I want to efficiently update widget and avoid `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: RemoteViews for widget update exceeds maximum bitmap memory usage`
My widget has three buttons(previous,play,next) ,progress bar(show current position of track) and image view (show cover of current track). The problem is i need to update the widget really often(every second for showing progress) and i often get IllegalArgumentException.
See my code below. Brief explanation : I store widget view in global variable (for better perfomance). startAlarm() - starting alarm manager to send broadcast every second.
The main question - How to improve perfomance and avoid IllegalArgumentException?

```
private static RemoteViews views;
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);

        String action = intent.getAction();
        AppWidgetManager wm = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        ComponentName cm = new ComponentName(context,SmallBiggerWidget.class);
        int[] ids = wm.getAppWidgetIds(cm);
        if(ids.length < 1)
            return;

        if(views == null){
            views = getViews(context);
        }else if(action.equals(ACTION_TRACK_CHANGED)){
            setNewAudioToView(context,views);
            setIconPlayToViews(views);
            setProgressTotView(views);
        }else if(action.equals(ACTION_PAUSE) || action.equals(ACTION_PLAY)){
            setIconPlayToViews(views);
        }else if(action.equals(ACTION_PROGRESS_UPDATE)){
            setProgressTotView(views);
        }else if(action.equals(PlayingService.ACTION_RELOAD_IMAGE)){
            setNewImageToView(PlayingService.audios.get(PlayingService.indexTrack),context,views);
        }
       for(int id : ids){
                wm.updateAppWidget(id,views);
            }
        if(isPlaying){
            startAlarm(context);
        }else{
            cancelAlarm(context);
        }
    }
```

The couse of IllegalArgumentException isn't big cover (i scale cover for small size) ,also i get this error even without imageView;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have to answer on my own question. The cause of `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` was static variable `RemoteViews views` because when i call `views.setTextViewText(R.id.text,text)` 
this put text into `RemoteViews` but previous text isn't deleted (`RemoteViews` contains all texts that i put to him).

How to avoid this problem? You should to every time create new instance of `RemoteViews`.

How to improve perfomance? You should to put into `RemoteViews` only what you want to change and call `wm.partiallyUpdateAppWidget(ids,views);`

Comment: I had the same problem with setting bitmaps on RemoteImageView, looking at the source I saw RemoteView has a BitmapCache which kept growing... thanks for the tip!